# How to select distinct occurrences used in different table

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have 4 tables:

```
         Table Pizzas                             Table Burgers
-------------------------------          --------------------------------
id item     pizza_id restaurant          id item     burger_id restaurant
-- ------   -------- ----------          -- ------   --------- ----------
1  cheese   2                14          1  cheese   32                14
...                                      ...

         Table Restaurant                          Table Items
--------------------------------         --------------------------------
id name                                  id name   price
-- -----------------------------         -- ------ -----
14 Los Pollos Hermanos                   1  cheese     2
...                                      2  oyster     4
                                         ...
```

I would like to select (in Microsoft Access), all the used `items` for a particular `restaurant`.

So I wrote this:

```
SELECT * FROM (((Items
LEFT JOIN Burgers
ON Items.name = Burgers.name)
LEFT JOIN Pizzas
ON Items.name = Pizzas.name)
LEFT JOIN Restaurant
ON 
    Restaurant.id = Burgers.restaurant AND
    Restaurant.id = Pizzas.restaurant)
WHERE
    Restaurant.name LIKE 'Los Pollos Hermanos'
ORDER BY
    Items.id
ASC
```

The problem is that I get many time the same entries and the query takes 5 minutes to execute. If I add the `SELECT DISTINCT` keyword, I don't get all the entries I need.

How should I write such SQL query?

Comment: Have you considered UNION ALL?

Comment: I don't know about `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `UNION` between the result of two separate queries. The `UNION` operation returns the union of two result sets, purged of the duplicates (`UNION ALL` is the same but without this latter step).

```
select  id, item
from    Pizzas t1
join    Restaurant t2
on      t1.restaurant = t2.id
where   t2.name = 'Los Pollos Hermanos'
union
select  id, item
from    Burgers t1
join    Restaurant t2
on      t1.restaurant = t2.id
where   t2.name = 'Los Pollos Hermanos'
```

If you want to order this final result, you have to do it outside of this query

```
select  id, item
from    (
            select  id, item
            from    Pizzas t1
            join    Restaurant t2
            on      t1.restaurant = t2.id
            where   t2.name = 'Los Pollos Hermanos'
            union
            select  id, item
            from    Burgers t1
            join    Restaurant t2
            on      t1.restaurant = t2.id
            where   t2.name = 'Los Pollos Hermanos'
        )
order by id
```

Note that in your example you don't need the `join` with `Items`, because you already have all you need on the `Pizzas` and `Burgers` tables.